# Adding delay to a $.post jquery request

Tags: jquery, post, delay

I'm sending a jquery $.post request on any checkbox change in a form.
What I want is to delay the $.post for 500 ms in case a user checks more than one checkbox rapidly, to avoid multiple useless requests.

Here's my code, I've added a setTimeout function that seems to work with everything except this $.post function...

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('.checkbox').change(function() {

        delay(function(){                             
            $.post("/?page_id=4", $("#selectors").serialize(), function(data){
                $('#results').html(data);
            }); 
        });

    }, 1000 );

});
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: I usually use setTimeout like that: `timer = window.setTimeout(function, 1000);`

Comment: Isn't the "}, 1000" at the wrong place? Shouldn't it be the second argument of the delay() function instead of the change() function?

Comment: @ElianEbbing @Phil what Elian says. Your passing `1000` to `.change`. Also default `timer` to `undefined` or you'll accidentally kill the `setTimeout` with `id === 0`

Comment: @ElianEbbing you're absolutely right, I missed that one, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/nGTN4/)

this:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {

    delay(function(){                             
        $.post("/?page_id=4", $("#selectors").serialize(), function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
        }); 
    });

}, 1000 );
```

should be:

```
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {

        delay(function(){    
            alert('post');            
            $.post("/?page_id=4", $("#selectors").serialize(), function(data){
                $('#results').html(data);
            }); 
        }, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can't believed I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I hate when I do something like that but it happens to us all at some point :P

Answer (score 5):

jQuery already has a delay function:

```
$(window).delay(500).queue(function() {
  $.post({});
});
```

Comment: Update: I've added $.dequeue() and it runs as many times as you press the checkbox, just with intervals, so it beats the purpose.